# error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename x> x functionA (x, x);

int main ()
{
    functionA <double, double, double> (1, 1) << "\n";
}

template <typename x> x functionA (x arg1, x arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

This code results in:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘functionA(int, int)’
```

What can be the reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function template has one template parameter only, and you're passing `3` template arguments to it:

```
functionA <double, double, double> (1, 1) << "\n";
```

Why `3` template arguments?

Just write:

```
functionA <double> (1, 1);
```

Or you can simply let the compiler deduce the template argument, as:

```
functionA(1.0, 1.0);  //template argument deduced as double!
functionA(1, 1);     //template argument deduced as int!
```

Comment: Doesn't `functionA <double, double, double>` mean that the return type is `double` and the other two arguments are also `double`?

Comment: @Anisha: There is only one *type parameter* in the first function template which is `x`. And same type is used as function parameter and as return type.

Comment: @Anisha if the arguments are of the same type you don't need to specify the type multiple times.

Comment: @Anisha: Even if the template parameter is getting applied in 3 places, two arguments and a return type, All 3 of them have to be of the same type, since the function template takes only one template parameter, so you only need to specify `double` once.

Comment: @Als Yeah that means the compiler doesn't like to be instructed more that once. :rolleyes: :D

Comment: @Anisha: No, it means when you do it in a wrong way. It's like calling `f` as `f(2,2,2)` simply because parameter `p` has been used  3 times, as : `int f(int p) { return p*p;}`.

Comment: @Anisha: It's compiler's way of saying, `I am smarter than the programmer` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong here. First, you only need to specify one type for the template:

```
functionA<double>(1, 1)
```

Secondly, you are missing the `std::cout` at the beginning of that line.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong: `functionA <double, double, double> (1, 1)`. You are trying to call the `functionA()` with three template parameters while your declaration of `functionA` has only 1 template parameter.

Beside that, the `<< "\n";` after the call does not make any sense either.

Answer (score 1):

The line should be,

```
std::cout << functionA <double> (1, 1) << "\n";
^^^^^^^missing          ^^^^^^only 1 argument
```

Because, `functionA` takes only 1 template argument and thus you should *call explicitly* only with exactly one template argument.

The 3 arguments are needed in the case had there been your `functionA` was like,

```
template <typename x, typename y, typename z>
x functionA (y arg1, z arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Nawaz's post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the types multiple times. 
If your return type and the argument to the function is same, then you don't even need to   specify the type. The below code compiles fine.

```
std::cout << functionA(1, 1) << std::endl;
```